# jQuery iframe disappears after appending content

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

after injecting my content into an iframe within the fancybox. The frame is visible for 1 second and then disappears. That happens in chrome and firefox.

Here ist my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

var f, txt, d, ifrmwin,edd;

var getContent = function(){
    return $("#iframe-content").contents().find("html").html();
};

$('.push_preview_lightbox_menu_iphone').fancybox({    

type: 'iframe',
  onComplete: function(){
     $('#fancybox-content iframe').removeAttr("src");
    var $iframeWrap = $("<div id=\"preview_smartphone\" style=\"margin: 0 auto; width: 550px;height:445px;\"></div>")
                  .append( 
                      $('<div style=\"width: 350px;height: 445px;overflow: hidden;cursor: pointer;margin-left: 45px;\"></div>') 
                      .append( 
                            $('<iframe></iframe>', {id: 'preview-iframe',width:"268px", height:"445px"})
                        )
               );
    eff = $('#fancybox-content iframe')[0].contentWindow.document;
    $("html", eff).append($iframeWrap);
    edd = $("#preview-iframe")[0].contentWindow.document;
    $("html", edd).append(getContent());
    },

});
});
</script>
```

iFrame is the same domain as the rest of the page.

Have anybody an idea?

THank you very much and best regards!

**EDIT:**

Okay..Here is the solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

var f, txt, d, ifrmwin,edd;

var getContent = function(){
    return $("#iframe-content").contents().find("html").html();
};

$('.push_preview_lightbox_menu_iphone').fancybox({    

'content': function() {
        return $('div#content').html() + '<div id="preview_smartphone" style="margin: 0 auto;">'
        + '<div style="width: 250px;height: 445px;overflow: hidden;cursor: pointer;margin-left: 45px;">'
        + '<iframe width="268px" height="445px" id="preview-iframe" frameborder="0">'
        + '</iframe></div></div>';
    },
  onComplete: function(){
    eff = $('#preview-iframe')[0].contentWindow.document;
    $("body", eff).append(getContent());
    },

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: You remove the `src` attribute and replace it with another iframe without a src? An iframe without a src is empty isn't it?

Comment: No, that's not the problem. An iframe doesn't need a source, if you append content to it. :)

Comment: Do you have a sample URL?

Comment: No, i'm very sorry. This is lokal website within an intra net. :(